# Mongodb reporting ENOTFOUND issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replicaset

I am developing a node application that points to a QA database. The database has 2 replica sets. When I start my node app, an ENOTFOUND issue was logged in the console.

```
C:\Users\xliu\WebstormProjects\gns-pages\api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\replset.js:365
      process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
MongoError: failed to connect to server [ip-10-16-89-129:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip-10-16-89-129 ip-10-16-89-129:27017]
at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xliu\WebstormProjects\gns-pages\api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:336:35)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xliu\WebstormProjects\gns-pages\api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:280:12)
```

However, when I pinged the server in the console, it showed no package was lost in transmission.

```
Pinging sports-pages-dev-mongo-db-a.labs.gracenote.com [10.16.89.169] with 32 bytes of data:
             Reply from 10.16.89.169: bytes=32 time=143ms TTL=240
             Reply from 10.16.89.169: bytes=32 time=167ms TTL=240
             Reply from 10.16.89.169: bytes=32 time=179ms TTL=240
             Reply from 10.16.89.169: bytes=32 time=105ms TTL=240
```

I am using Mongoose 4.11.10 and Window 10 for OS. Can anyone share some thoughts on this, I will be very appreciated.

Comment: Because you typed an IP address with dashes `-` and not "dots" `.`. Look at your error output. You have entered `ip-10-16-89-129` as a string that should simply be `10.16.89.129`

Comment: @NeilLunn The error was generated by the mongo module itself, I didn't modify anything in the original code.

Comment: It's not MongoDB. Show the code where you are providing the connection string if you still do not understand. It's your input, because the driver does not insert such strings.

Comment: "mongoDatabase": "sports-pages-dev-mongo-db-a.labs.gracenote.com,sports-pages-dev-mongo-db-b.labs.gracenote.com,sports-pages-dev-mongo-db-c.labs.gracenote.com:27017/gns-pages?replicaSet=sdi-rs-test", this is how I define my connection string.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46136559/edit) and "copy & paste" your actual code. No pictures. No abstract descriptions. Use your actual code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a description of how you are expected to ask questions here.